# React Router with multiple levels of dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm working on a project that requires multiple levels of dynamic routing.  To wrap my head around the idea of dynamic routing, I used the recursive routing example in React Router documentation. However, this(obviously) shows the previous routes and that's not what I need. I'm only interested in showing the final route and I'm not savvy or experienced enough to figure out how to modify this to make it work.

I've created a codesandbox showing the working recursive routing. https://codesandbox.io/s/j29xlkr6qy

The functionality I am looking for is if the user navigates to the url ***domain.com/opt3/ch2-opt2/ch3-opt3***, where ***/opt3/ch2-opt2/ch3-opt3/*** are all dynamic, they will only see the route for ***ch3-opt3***. The problem with the recursive example is, obviously, that it shows the routes for ***opt3***, ***ch2-opt2***, and ***ch3-opt3***, rather than just the route for ***ch3-opt3***.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. React Router v4 allows for multiple parameters. So, the URL structure of domain.com/:id1/:id2/:id3/:id4, yields match.id1, match.id2, match.id3, and match.id4.